# Run software as admin user, but in the current user context

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, runas

Here is my situation: I have a single software that demands admin rights. That software needs to be run by commom users. Right-clicking and "Run as administrator" does not do the trick, therefore I used the `runas` application in order to run such software as another account that has admin rights, but logged as a common user. So the commom user will execute a `.bat` like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /profile /user:admin_user /savecred "path_to_software"
```

The problem is, since I'm running the software as `admin_user`, I'm also inside his context. For example, when I try to save a file from inside that software, the "Save as" dialog will by default, open `admin_user`'s folders, and not current user's folders. This also happens for the default printers and so on. Every aspect of the software that interacts with Windows, will be inside `admin_user` context.

What I need, is to run the software as `admin_user` (or with admin rights), but inside the context of the logged (current) user, so that when I open "Save as" dialog, for example, I get the current user folders, not `admin_user` folders. Is that even possible?

Comment: If the current user does not have Administrator permissions, then you cannot run the application as another user in order to escalated the permissions of the process, as the current user.  Even if "run as Administrator" was working, you would still be running it as the Administrator user you provided the credentials for, because the current user doesn't have those permissions to do so.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what type of software do you have that *"demands admin rights"* to work properly?  That may have been relatively common 10-15 years ago, but these days that is highly unusual.

Comment: @Run5k We use this financial third party software that is extremely outdated. We have had lots of issues with it, demanding admin rights is just the tip of the iceberg. Unfortunately, for a number of reasons, that is our only option right now, but we're planning to change it in the future.

Comment: While I can certainly empathize with your problem, I'm afraid that there probably isn't an ideal solution readily available.  Of course, the best-case scenario would involve upgrading your financial software to something that doesn't have those outdated requirements for admin privileges.  Beyond that, it sounds like the only way to achieve what you want to do would involve granting each user's account admin privileges on the local machine... but again, that is much less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Use compatibility mode of Windows

[image]

it seems to do the trick you want