# Is it possible to elevate an application to run as admin without changing user context (profile)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac, user-profiles, profile

I've been coming across this more often as I roll out Windows 10 workstations and encounter various issues with our current software stack.

Often I'll need to run an application or utility which requires the user context, that is, the user's profile (most often for application data).

As such my prior ways of elevating users is no longer working, since, when I Run as Administrator, the utility or program is now looking for or saving things in the Administrator's profile instead of within the user context I'm currently trying to troubleshoot.

So far in these cases I've simply elevated the user to an admin in order to bypass this issue, but I'm looking for a way to accomplish this without having to have the user log in and out at the start and end of my work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Just saw [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1245827/run-software-as-admin-user-but-in-the-current-user-context), but no answers :(

An example I came across today: A user's Quickbooks Enterpirse Desktop 19 was having issues with emailing PDF files of invoices. Intuit has a utility which re-installs the Microsoft XPS drivers, and purges a bunch of temporary files from the user's appdata folder (among other things). Therefore, it does not fix the problem when it's run outside the user's context.

Comment: `1.` Look over changing the application level configurations & tell the application where to store files, file structure, database, or whatever & then change the user context to elevate or whatever. `2.` Look into granting the user account elevated access to whatever it needs to run on Windows so you don't even need to change user context.

Answer (score 0):

RunAsTool is portable freeware which allows standard users to run a specific program with administrator privileges without the need to enter the administrator password

https://www.sordum.org/8727/runastool-v1-4/

this is a software I found not to long ago very useful when needing to run like device manager or disk management with elevated permissions.